# Explanation for a specific command in a awk

Tags: awk

Can you explain me what doing this command ' dateA="$dateA" '?

`awk 'FNR>1 && dateA<=$5' FS='|' dateA="$dateA" "$infile"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR > 1 && dateA <= $5 ' FS='|' dateA="$dateA" "$infile"
```

- `FNR` is variable gives you total number of records, related to current file, don't get confused with variable `NR`, `FNR` and `NR` value will be same as long as `awk` reads first file, for second file, variable `FNR` will reset, whereas `NR` doesn't.

This is how `FNR` and `NR` works in `awk`

```
$ seq 1 5 >file1
$ seq 1 3 >file2
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat file2
1
2
3

$ awk '{print "Current line : "$0,"File: "FILENAME,"FNR : ",FNR,"NR : ",NR}' file1 file2
Current line : 1 File: file1 FNR :  1 NR :  1
Current line : 2 File: file1 FNR :  2 NR :  2
Current line : 3 File: file1 FNR :  3 NR :  3
Current line : 4 File: file1 FNR :  4 NR :  4
Current line : 5 File: file1 FNR :  5 NR :  5
Current line : 1 File: file2 FNR :  1 NR :  6
Current line : 2 File: file2 FNR :  2 NR :  7
Current line : 3 File: file2 FNR :  3 NR :  8
```

- `FNR > 1 && dateA <= $5` If no of records read is greater than 1 and variable `dateA` is less than or equal to 5th field/column, we get boolean true state, so such line will be printed
- `FS='|'`  `FS` is input field separator, you can also set it like

  - `awk -F'|' '{ .... }'`         OR
  - `awk -v FS='|' '{ .... }'`     OR
  - `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{ .... }'`
- `dateA="$dateA"` `dateA` is `awk` variable whose value is taken from your shell variable `$dateA`, similarly you can set it like

  - `awk -v dateA="$dateA" '{ .... }'`

Your above command can be rewritten like below also

```
awk -F'|' -v dateA="$dateA" 'FNR>1 && dateA <= $5' "$infile"
```

and some people prefer `awk 'condition{action}'` for better reading, so you can also write it as

```
awk -F'|' -v dateA="$dateA" 'FNR>1 && dateA <= $5{ print }' "$infile"
                                    ^                 ^
                                    |                 |
                          If this condition is true   |
                                                      |
                                   Action is to print line,
                                   print or print $0 is same
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following explanation and let me know if this helps you.

***Explanation:*** Kindly don't run following awk, it is expanded for explanation purposes only.

```
awk '
FNR>1 && dateA<=$5 ##FNR denotes the number of current line in awk so here 2 conditions with AND conditions are being checked.
                   ##1st is if current line number is greater than 1 and second is variable named dateA value should be lesser
                   ##and equal to 5. 
                   ##So let me explain here awk works on method of condition and then action, so if any condition is TRUE then action
                   ##will happen, here condition is there but NO action defined, so by default print action will happen. print of 
                   ##current line.
' 
FS='|'             ##FS denotes the field separator, in awk we could define the field separator by ourselves too, so making it here as |
dateA="$dateA"     ##creating variable named dateA whose value is equal to shell variable named dateA. In awk if we have to assign 
                   ##shell variable values to awk variables we have to create an awk variable and then assign shell variable value to
                   ##it.
"$infile"          ##Mentioning the Input_file name here which awk has to go through. Point to be noted here the "$infile" means
                   ##it is a shell variable (as we all know to print shell variable value we have to use "$infile")
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK allows assigning internal variable in the arguments with the form `var=value`.  Since AWK does not have access to shell variables `dateA="$dateA"` is used to "export" `dateA` to the AWK script.

Note that assignment arguments occur during file processing, after `BEGIN`, and can be used in-between files:

```
$ echo >file1; echo >file2
$ awk -vx=0 '
        BEGIN {
                print "BEGIN", x
        }
        {
                print FILENAME, x
        }
        END {
                print "END", x
        }' x=1 file1 x=2 file2 x=3
BEGIN 0
file1 1
file2 2
END 3
```